# Copy all folders in a library to another library

Tags: client-object-model, csom, sharepoint-library, c-sharp

I have a Sharepoint library which is having 10 folders, i want to move those folders(along with files inside those folders) from one library to another library with in same site using CSOM**(C#)**. Please help me out.